# Gradle Replace text in jsp using filter

Tags: jsp, build, replace, gradle

I have a jsp that contains a css link that looks like

```
<link type="text/css" href="/css/login-min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

In order to keep browsers from caching the css file we replace `login-min.css` with the name of the css and a timestamp or version number

```
login-min.css?t=432432423423...
```

In ant I would do something like

```
<tstamp>
  <format property="current.time" pattern="MMddyyyyhhmmssaa" offset="-5" unit="hour" />
</tstamp>

<replace dir="${deploy.path}/${name}/WEB-INF/jsp" value="login-min.css?t=${current.time}">
  <include name="includes/login_css_include.jsp" />
  <replacetoken>login-min.css</replacetoken>
</replace>
```

For gradle I've updated the jsp page to look like

```
<link type="text/css" href="/css/@loginCSS@" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and in the build.gradle am doing

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens
war {
  webInf {
    from ("${webAppDir}/WEB-INF/jsp") {
      include: "/includes/login_css_include.jsp"
      filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [loginCSS: 'login-min.css?v=1'])
    }
  }
}
```

but this isn't working.

This one works but it changes the source... I just want the files in the war to be modified.

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens
war {
  webInf {
    from ("${webAppDir}/WEB-INF/jsp/includes/login_css_include.jsp") {
      it.eachFile {
        ant.replace(file: it.file, token: "@loginCSS@", value: "login-min.css?v=1")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm brand new to gradle am I going about this totally incorrectly?  Anyone needed to do something like this before?  Using gradle 1.0-milestone-1.

Thanks

Comment: Have you run with `gradle -i` or `gradle -d` to get more info about what's happening when you build the war?

Comment: @Emil - Thanks for the interest.  I never ran with those options, the first try didn't appear to be doing anything and the second didn't do what I wanted so I didn't go further than that, probably should have.  My answer below does work if you want to take a look at that.  It may not be a very intelligent way of doing it but it does do the job.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, this seems to work:

**jsp page**:

```
<link type="text/css" href="/css/@loginCSS@" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**build.gradle**:

```
war {
   filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: ['loginCSS': 'login-min.css'])
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work when I add the timestamp as in `filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [loginCSS: "login-min.css?t=${now}", allCSS: "all-min.css?t=${now}", allJS: "all-min.js?t=${now}"])`.  I get `Cause: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

Comment: @josh, I got around this same scenario by using toString().  In your example, it would look like this: filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [loginCSS: "login-min.css?t=${now}".toString(), allCSS: "all-min.css?t=${now}".toString, allJS: "all-min.js?t=${now}".toString()])

Comment: This will change the encoding of my file, for example, jsp file. Is there anyway we can keep or set the file encoding?

Answer (score 5):

Yet another variant to try out (it works in my case to overcome this bug http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1566#)

```
war {   
   eachFile {
      if (it.name == 'yourFile.jsp') {
        it.filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: [...])
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This helped me.  I was doing something with `expand` that was breaking.  Selecting just the file I wanted to `expand` using this strategy fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this fits with the groovy/gradle style this is how I was able to accomplish this.

jsp file now looks like this:

```
<link type="text/css" href="/css/${loginCSS}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and the gradle.build like this:

```
war {
  eachFile {
    if (it.name == 'login_css_include.jsp') {
      it.expand(loginCSS: "login-min.css?v=1")
    }
  }
}
```

Utilizing a timestamp looks like this:

```
war {
  eachFile {
    if (it.name == 'login_css_include.jsp') {
      def now = new Date()
      it.expand(loginCSS: "login-min.css?t=${now.getTime()}")
    }
  }
}
```

Edit - as Axel points out below in the comments, this solution has trouble when it runs across binary files or files with JSP EL expressions.

Comment: This fails me, as it strangely tries to replace tokens inside binary files as well (favicon.ico in my case). Also it seems to conflict with JSP EL...

Comment: I ran into the exact same thing.  I got EOL parsing errors when it ran into some jstl stuff.  It works in this case since I'm looking at a very particular file that isn't a binary file and doesn't have jstl.  I'm open to another solution that works better in all cases but I haven't found it.

Answer (score 0):

We've done similar (but not quite exactly the same) things just creating `java.io.File`s and manipulating them, then including them into the .war using the `from{}` or `webInf{}` with a `fileTree`.

You could look into something like that, but since this seems to be handled pretty well by ant, have you looked into using ant directly from gradle [like this](http://www.gradle.org/1.0-milestone-1/docs/userguide/ant.html)?

Comment: I bet one could do an ant.replace in the eachFile similarly to the expand in my answer. That might get around the binary and jstl issues that solution has.  Ill have to try that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set encoding by(because by default it will change the file encoding):

```
war {
    filteringCharset = 'UTF-8'
    filesMatching( '**/*.jsp' ) {
        filter ReplaceTokens, tokens: [
                'versionDate': "${new Date().format('yyyyMMdd')}".toString(),
                'copyright'  : "${new Date().format('yyyy')}".toString()
        ]
    }
}
```